# Display images in django web app from mongo db

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to display images in django html web page from mongodb.
I saved images in mongodb using gridfs with vendor_id as an extra value.
Then i retrieved them like :

my models.py:

```
def getImages(self, vendor_id):
    img_name = []
    img_ids = []
    images = []
    for each in self.files.find({'vendor_id':vendor_id}):   ####self.files is a variable which store value db['fs.files']
        img_ids.append(each['_id'])
        img_name.append(each['name'])

    for iid in img_ids:
        images.append(self.gfs.get(iid).read())

    return images
```

my views.py:

```
def vendorData(request):
    vendors = Vendors()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        vendor_id = request.GET.get('vendor_id')
        if vendors.checkValidVendorId(vendor_id) == False:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Vendor Id.')
        else:
            vendor_details = vendors.getVendorDetails(vendor_id)
            vendor_name = vendor_details[0]
            restaurant_name = vendor_details[1]
            images = vendors.getImages(vendor_id)
            context_dict = {'vendor_id':vendor_id,
                            'vendor_name':vendor_name,
                            'restaurant_name':restaurant_name
                            'images':images}
            return render(request, 'vendor_data.html', context_dict)
```

I passed the binary data of multiple images to views.py in a list. 
How to show this data in django web page?

Note: I can show these images by saving them temporarily. But is there any other way i can display these images without saving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use the "data" uri format, which allows you to pass the image as a base64-encoded string. Of course, you'll need to encode the images first in your `getImages` function:

```
for iid in img_ids:
    images.append(base64.b64encode(self.gfs.get(iid).read()))
```

and in the template you can output the data directly:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img }}">
{% endfor %}
```

(obviously, replace png with jpg or whatever as necessary).